# C++ std::string alternative to strcpy?

Tags: c++, stdstring, strcpy

I know there is a similarly titled question already on SO but I want to know my options for this specific case.

MSVC compiler gives a warning about strcpy:

```
1>c:\something\mycontrol.cpp(65): warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or
variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable
deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
```

Here's my code:

```
void MyControl::SetFontFace(const char *faceName)
{
    LOGFONT lf;

    CFont *currentFont = GetFont();
    currentFont->GetLogFont(&lf);
    strcpy(lf.lfFaceName, faceName); <--- offending line
    font_.DeleteObject();
    // Create the font.
    font_.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

    // Use the font to paint a control.
    SetFont(&font_);
}
```

Note `font_` is an instance variable. `LOGFONT` is a windows structure where `lfFaceName` is defined as `TCHAR lfFaceName[LF_FACESIZE]`.

What I'm wondering is can I do something like the following (and if not why not):

```
void MyControl::SetFontFace(const std::string& faceName)
...
  lf.lfFaceName = faceName.c_str();
...
```

Or if there is a different alternative altogether then let me know.

Comment: You can ignore this warning, strcpy is not deprecated.  Define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` permanently in your settings and be done with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804154/copy-of-const-char-using-stdstring-constructor

Comment: The danger with strcpy is that if the source string is not NULL terminated, or is longer than the destination buffer, you will get a buffer overflow - which is one of the most common sources of security flaws in C / C++ code.  strcpy_s also takes the size of the destination buffer, and guarantees that after successful completion, the destination buffer will be null terminated.

Comment: `strncpy` is more portable, same safety.

Comment: @MooingDuck, the problem with `strncpy` is that it is broken: if it hast to truncate it won't null terminate. So better to use a quick wrapper that always adds zero at the end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you're getting the security warning is, your `faceName` argument could point to a string that is *longer* than `LF_FACESIZE` characters, and then `strcpy` would blindly overwrite whatever comes after `lfFaceName` in the `LOGFONT` structure.  You do have a bug.

You should **not** blindly fix the bug by changing `strcpy` to `strcpy_s`, because:

1. The `*_s` functions are unportable Microsoft inventions almost all of which duplicate the functionality of other C library functions that *are* portable.  They should never be used, even in a program not intended to be portable (as this appears to be).
2. Blind changes tend to not actually fix this class of bug.  For instance, the "safe" variants of `strcpy` (`strncpy`, `strlcpy`, `strcpy_s`) simply truncate the string if it's too long, which in this case would make you try to load the wrong font.  Worse, `strncpy`  omits the NUL terminator when it does that, so you'd probably just move the crash inside `CreateFontIndirect` if you used that one.  The *correct* fix is to check the length up front and fail the entire operation if it's too long.  At which point `strcpy` becomes safe (because you know it's not too long), although I prefer `memcpy` because it makes it obvious to future readers of the code that I've thought about this.
3. `TCHAR` and `char` are not the same thing; copying either a C-style `const char *` string or a C++ `std::string` into an array of `TCHAR` without a proper encoding conversion may produce complete nonsense.  (Using `TCHAR` is, in my experience, always a mistake, and the biggest problem with it is that code like this will appear to work correctly in an ASCII build, and will still *compile* in UNICODE mode, but will then fail catastrophically at runtime.)

You certainly can use `std::string` to *help* with this problem, but it won't get you out of needing to check the length and manually copy the string. I'd probably do it like this.  Note that I am using `LOGFONTW` and `CreateFontIndirectW` and an explicit conversion from UTF-8 in the `std::string`.  Note also that chunks of this were cargo-culted out of MSDN and none of it has been tested.  Sorry.

```
void MyControl::SetFontFace(const std::string& faceName)
{
    LOGFONTW lf;
    this->font_.GetLogFontW(&lf);

    int count = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS,
                                    faceName.data(), faceName.length(),
                                    lf.lfFaceName, LF_FACESIZE - 1)
    if (count <= 0)
        throw GetLastError(); // FIXME: use a real exception

    lf.lfFaceName[count] = L'\0'; // MultiByteToWideChar does not NUL-terminate.

    this->font_.DeleteObject();
    if (!this->font_.CreateFontIndirectW(&lf))
        throw GetLastError(); // FIXME: use a real exception

    // ...
}
```

Comment: `strcpy_s` guarantees null termination, it's not a duplicate of `strcpyn` which is why it's a different function

Comment: @shf301: True but it blindly causes the same problem with truncation. Thus the advice here is sound.

Comment: @shf301 I didn't know that; that makes it a duplicate of `strlcpy` rather than `strncpy`.  (`strlcpy` itself, alas, is a BSDism, but MS really could stand to learn that it is *not* a good thing to make up one's own names for stuff.)

Comment: It is my considered opinion that the `_s` functions should not be used *even in code not intended to be portable*, because the people who made them up ought to be punished for their failure to check whether they were duplicating existing APIs, and refusing to use them is the only stick available.

Comment: Technically they weren't duplicating existing APIs, since they added the parameter validation error return values and the buffer size parameter is always expressed in bytes (while lengths are expressed in standard-character-widths, which is an important distinction if you're trying to write _UNICODE agnostic code).

Comment: @zwol the faceName argument should really be const std::basic_string<TCHAR> & - as horrible as that may look, it then becomes the same type as the elements contained in lfFaceName. The third argument to memcpy should then also be adjusted to the size of a TCHAR.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou It has been my (somewhat limited) experience that every use of `TCHAR` is a bug; one should use exclusively the explicitly-tagged `W` APIs, converting from/to UTF-8 in `std::string` on the fly as necessary.  I'll update my answer to make that clear.

Answer (score 3):

`lf.lfFaceName = faceName.c_str();`

No you shouldn't do that because you are making a local copy of the poitner to the data held inside the std::string. If the c++ string changes, or is deleted, the pointer is no longer valid, and if lFaceName decides to change the data this will almost certainly break the std::string.

Since you need to copy a c string, you need a 'c'  function, then strcpy_s (or it's equivalent) is the safe alternative

Comment: I don't think it works like that if lf.lfFaceName is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried? Given the information in your post, the assignment should generate a compiler error because you're trying to assign a pointer to an array, which does not work in C(++).

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct LOGFONT {
 char lfFaceName[3];
};


int main() {
        struct LOGFONT f;
        string foo="bar";
        f.lfFaceName = foo.c_str();
        return 0;
}
```

leads to

```
x.c:13: error: incompatible types in assignment of `const char*' to `char[3]'
```

I'd recommend using a secure strcpy alternative like the warning says, given that you know the size of the destination space anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum { LF_FACESIZE = 256 }; // = 3 // test too-long input
struct LOGFONT
{
    char lfFaceName[LF_FACESIZE];
};

int main()
{
    LOGFONT f;
    std::string foo("Sans-Serif");
    std::copy_n(foo.c_str(), foo.size()+1 > LF_FACESIZE ? LF_FACESIZE : foo.size()+1,
                f.lfFaceName);

    std::cout << f.lfFaceName << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`lf.lfFaceName = faceName.c_str();` won't work for two reasons (assuming you change faceName to a std:string)

1. The lifetime of the pointer returned by c_str() is temporary.  It's only valid as long as the fileName object doesn't change and in alive.
2. The line won't compile. .c_str() returns a pointer to a char, and lfFaceName is a character array and can't be assigned to.  You need to do something to fill in the string array, to fill in the bytes at lfFaceName, and pointer assignment doesn't do that.

There isn't anything C++ that can help here, since lfFaceName is a C "string".  You need to use a C string function, like strcpy or strcpy_s.  You can change your code to:

```
strcpy_s(lf.lfFaceName, LF_FACESIZE, faceName);
```

Comment: I think you meant to write `strncpy`, not `strcpy`.  Also, you have a syntax error in your example code.

Comment: No, you meant `strncpy`.  As I explain in my answer, `strcpy_s` should never be used.  Also, you still haven't fixed the syntax error.